# How many connections does rails open in a recursive function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that has a recursive link to itself, like a linked list. If I'm writing a function like the below (pardon my syntax, Ruby is not my language of choice) to follow the chain to the end. Assuming this is part of an Active Record model and `next` is a foreign key to the next node, what happens behind the scenes for this function? How many separate connections to my MySQL db is Active Record opening, and how long do they stick around for?

```
module LinkedList
  class Node < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :value
    has_one :next, foreign_key: 'id' class_name: 'Source::Incident'

    def fetch_all_nodes(current_node=nil, all_nodes=nil)

      current_node = current_node ? current_node : self
      all_nodes = all_nodes ? all_nodes : [self]

      if current_node.next
        all_nodes = fetch_all_nodes(current_node.next, all_nodes << current_node)

      all_nodes
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: Can you add your basic model definition as well?

Comment: Fleshed it out a bit - this is meant to be a simple hypothetical example so if more detail is needed please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

As written as a recursive function, you would have one call SQL call per node. Next is called, gets the related nodes, and caches the value. (You can reload it if needed). As far as I can tell this implementation ends up with a single object per database record. If you ended up looking up an object that you already had stored, that would cause more objects, and more database lookups, but Rails has a query cache, so that can reduce such lookups.

You could have `all_nodes` instead return a [lazy enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html), and then if you don't end up inspecting the entire tail, you'd only have one call per node visited, and you could handle potentially infinite (or even looping) lists.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord` uses [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html) to connect to your datastore which has a default pool of 5 connections. So, at most, each instance of Rails/ActiveRecord will use a max number of database connections as the configured connection pool size.